# JSON error when trying to create an AWS execution role in command line

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to follow this tutorial here to create an execution role - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package-create.html

However, when I try and run the following command from the instructions

```
aws iam create-role --role-name lambda-ex --assume-role-policy-document "{"Version": "2012-10-17","Statement": [{ "Effect": "Allow", "Principal": {"Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"}, "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"}]}"
```

I get the error "An error occurred (MalformedPolicyDocument) when calling the CreateRole operation: This policy contains invalid Json".

I'm new to AWS so I'm not sure what's going on - can anyone help please?

Comment: are you on windows or linux/macos?

Comment: I'm using Windows

Comment: CMD or powershell?

Comment: I'm using CMD, will try in powershell

Comment: In powershell I get the following 

usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help

Unknown options: Version: 2012-10-17,Statement: [{ Effect: Allow, Principal: {Service: lambda.amazonaws.com}, Action: sts:AssumeRole}]}

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, as perjellycsc's advise to escape every `"` in the string I used:

```
aws iam create-role --role-name lambda-ex --assume-role-policy-document "{\"Version\": \"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\": [{ \"Effect\": \"Allow\", \"Principal\": {\"Service\": \"lambda.amazonaws.com\"}, \"Action\": \"sts:AssumeRole\"}]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes. **Note: this only works for Linux-like OS.**

```
aws iam create-role --role-name lambda-ex --assume-role-policy-document '{"Version": "2012-10-17","Statement": [{ "Effect": "Allow", "Principal": {"Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"}, "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"}]}'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer - I have tried this and get the following usage: 

aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help

Unknown options: [{, Effect:, Allow,, Principal:, {Service:, lambda.amazonaws.com},, Action:, sts:AssumeRole}]}', 2012-10-17,Statement:

I am using Windows if that makes a difference

Comment: Yeah, I guess my solution only works for Linux. Try escaping every `"` inside the string.